# How are oranges in the US or anywhere made seedless?

Tags: genetics, botany, food, ethnobiology, seeds

How are oranges in the US or anywhere made seedless? Please explain the broad principles and not the technicalities.

Comment: Neat question! No time to write up an answer now, but I'm sure someone will. In the meantime, see: http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-seedless-fruits-ar/

Comment: Related question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/why-cant-we-breed-watermelons-without-any-remaining-seeds-in-the-flesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oranges and other fruits are generally not actively made seedless. Rather, seeds may fail to develop due to either lack of fertilization (pollination) or a natural tendency. The natural production of unfertilized and thus seedless fruit is called [Parthenocarpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocarpy).

To quote the Scientific American article ([3](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-seedless-fruits-ar/)) mentioned by Oreotrephes:

> Fruit development normally begins when one or more egg cells in the
>   ovular compartment of the flower are fertilized by sperm nuclei from
>   pollen. In some plants, however, fruit develops without fertilization,
>   a phenomenon known as parthenocarpy. Parthenocarpic fruit has
>   advantages over seeded fruit: longer shelf life and greater consumer
>   appeal.
>
> The most frequent reasons for lack of seed development are pollination
>   failure, or nonfunctional eggs or sperm. In many plants,
>   self-incompatibility genes limit successful fertilization to
>   cross-pollination between genetically different male and female
>   parents. This property is exploited by citrus farmers who grow
>   seedless fruits, such as navel oranges and clementines. Because these
>   cultivars are self-incompatible, they fail to set seed when they are
>   planted in orchards of identical plants (clones). These plants have a
>   high frequency of parthenocarpy, however, so they still produce fruit.

Parthenocarpic varieties may arise from a lack of pollinators. From the Wikipedia page on [Parthenocarpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocarpy):

> Plants moved from one area of the world to another may not always be
>   accompanied by their pollinating partner and the lack of pollinators
>   has spurred human cultivation of parthenocarpic varieties. Some
>   parthenocarpic varieties have been developed as genetically modified
>   organisms.

To preserve the seedless trait, parthenocarpic trees can be propagated by [grafting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafting). It is possible that more kinds of seedless fruits will be engineered in the future ([3](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-seedless-fruits-ar/)):

> Plant biologists have learned that if the plant hormone auxin is
>   produced early in ovule development, parthenocarpic fruit can grow on
>   plants that do not usually exhibit this property. Thus, genetic
>   engineering will most likely give consumers parthenocarpic fruit in
>   many other species in the near future.